# What words Atbash plus Caesar cipher to other words?

Tags: cipher

If you Atbash cipher plus Caesar cipher after, you get a new set of ciphers, and I tried 4-letter words for Atbash plus Caesar shift 1 and I got:
cams <-> yaoi
ghat <-> Utah
haji <-> tars
hasp <-> tail
hemi <-> twos
jail <-> rasp
and a few more.

Why I used <-> instead of -> is because Atbash plus Caesar cipher reverses itself, so if A becomes B, B becomes A.

Definitions of obscure words(in order of pairs above):
Yaoi is a type of anime that has alot of male romance,
Ghat is a flight of steps leading to a river,
Haji is a Muslim who has been to Mecca as a pilgrim,
Hasp is a lock or connection,
Hemi is a prefix meaning half

Do you know any other Atbash plus Caesar pairs of words with shift other than 1?(Atbash cipher a word, and then Caesar cipher it, I surveyed 4-letter words for the 1-shift and got the pairs above.)

Sample Cipher:
Plain Text - abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1-shifted  - azyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcb

Comment: This is effectively a *list question* - one which can never be exhaustively answered, and for which any relevant answer is equally valid. (And inviting proper names as candidate "words" makes for a pretty much unending list of possibilities, as just about anything could be a proper name somewhere.) See in particular [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139623) for more reasons why these types of questions are generally off-topic everywhere on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots for almost every choice of Caesar shift. (And *some* for every choice.)

Here are a few examples.

- For a shift of 10, there are no examples (with the deliberately fairly small dictionary I used).
- For the traditional Caesar shift of 3: noon/poop (palindromes!), jury/tile, mice/quay, bile/bury, hog/vow.
- For ROT13: ditto/jetty, debt/jilt, big/leg.
- Some long ones: (9) butter/hopper, pewter/temper, pumice/towage, copper/gutter. (22) corned/theirs. A 7-letter example is (9) creeper/greeter. The only 8-letter examples are (9) pewterer/temperer, and (23) hospices/piehouse.
- Some that seem to go together one way or another: (5) pal/pet, (8) otto/toot, (9) offer/udder waxy/milk, (11) etch/grid, (12) elf/hag, (15) all/odd glad/idol, (18) carve/prawn, (19) rosy/beau, (20) bite/slap, bats/stab (the reverse of one another!), (21) suck/cask chat/snub, (22) evil/rank, (23) lied/lost bowl/vial.
- 22 also has dry/sex and grind/penis. Sorry.

There are many many more. I think this sort of thing is better done by computer than by hand, and the above were found that way (but of course selected by hand).

Answer (score 1):

The 3-shift(needs cleaning too):
ache -> cavy
achy -> cave
aloo -> croo
alow -> crog
aril -> clur

bias -> buck
bike -> busy
bile -> bury
bilk -> burs
bill -> burr
bink -> bups
birr -> bull
blow -> brog
blub -> brib
bock -> boas
bogy -> bowe
boil -> bour
boke -> bosy
boko -> boso
boks -> bosk
boll -> borr
bolo -> boro
blow -> brog
bony -> bope
boob -> boob
book -> boos
bool -> boor
bron -> blop
brog -> blow
broo -> bloo
brow -> blog
buck -> bias
bunk -> bips

calo -> acro
cask -> acks(anagram
)
case -> acky
chur -> Avil
clop -> Aron
clog -> arow
coin -> aoup
coij -> aout
crow -> alog

docs -> zoak
dodo -> zozo
dols -> zork
dope -> zony
dops -> zonk
dopy -> zone
dups -> zink
durr -> zill

ecce -> yaay

girn -> wulp
girr -> wull
goby -> wobe
gole -> wory
golp -> worn
gone -> wopy
gonk -> wops
gook -> woos
goon -> woop
goop -> woon
goor -> wool
gule -> wiry
guly -> wire
gups -> wink

hoke -> vosy
hole -> vory
hoon -> voop
hoop -> voon
Hyle -> very

jibb -> tubb
jill -> turr
jinn -> tupp
jobe -> toby
jock -> toas
join -> toup
joke -> tosy
joky -> tose
jole -> Tory
joll -> torr
jols -> tork
jors -> Tolk
jour -> toil
junk -> tips
jupe -> tiny
jure -> tily
jury -> tile

kail -> scur
kale -> scry
kaon -> scop
kibe -> suby
kiln -> surp
kilp -> surn
kipe -> suny
kipp -> sunn
kips -> sunk
kirs -> sulk
kias -> suck
kyak -> secs

lias -> ruck
like -> rusy
liny -> rupe
lipe -> runy
lire -> ruly
lirk -> ruls
lisk -> ruks
lobo -> robo
lode -> rozy
loin -> roup
loke -> rosy
loll -> rorr
lone -> ropy
look -> roos
loon -> roop
loop -> roon
loor -> rool(backwards!)
loos -> rook
lops -> ronk
lory -> role
loto -> rojo
luck -> Rias
lure -> rily
lunk -> rips
lune -> ripy
luny -> ripe

mice -> quay

nick -> puas
nips -> punk
nixy -> pufe
nock -> poas
node -> pozy
noil -> pour
none -> popy
nook -> poos
noon -> poop
noop -> poon(abackwards)
nope -> pony
nosy -> poke
noun -> poip
noup -> poin
nurr -> pill
nyas -> peck

ogre -> owly
olpe -> orny
ooze -> oody
oozy -> oode
oulk -> oirs
oups -> oink
owly -> ogre
owle -> ogly

peck -> nyas
pias -> nuck
pike -> nusy
pila -> nurc
pile -> nury
pill -> nurr
pipe -> nuny
pirs -> nulk
poke -> nosy
poky -> nose
pooh -> noov
pook -> noos
pool -> noor
poon -> noop(backwards)
poop -> noon
poor -> nool
poos -> nook
pops -> nonk
pory -> nole
pulk -> nirs
puls -> nirk
puly -> nire
purr -> nill(joll -> torr is similar since joll -(only caesar)> purr and torr -(only caesar)> nill)
pyas -> neck

quay -> mice
qop -> Mion

reck -> Lyas
reny -> lype
rick -> luas
ricy -> luae
Rias -> luck
roky -> lose
roll -> lorr
rone -> lopy
rook -> loos
roon -> llop(roon also goes to beef and psst!)
roop -> loon
roos -> look
rope -> lony
ropy -> lone
rory -> lole
rosy -> loke
roup -> loin
ruck -> lias

silo -> kuro
sips -> kunk
slob -> krob
sloe -> kroy
slop -> kron
slow -> krog
sloo -> kroo
slub -> krib
slur -> kril
solo -> koro
sols -> kork
soon -> koop
soop -> koon
sops -> konk
sour -> koil
sous -> koik
spun -> knip
spuj -> knit
suck -> kias
sulk -> kirs
sudd -> kizz
sups -> kink

tile -> jury
tils -> jurk
tips -> junk
tire -> July
toon -> joop
tops -> jonk
Tory -> jole
tuny -> jipe
typy -> Jene
typp -> Jenn
tyro -> jelo(again, punk -> nips is similar because Caesar cipher)

vire -> huly
vols -> hork
volk -> hors
vuln -> hirp

wice -> guay
wich -> guav
wili -> guru
will -> gurr
wily -> gure
winy -> gupe(also see 9: cote -> gupe)
wink -> gups
wock -> goas
woke -> gosy
wonk -> gops
wops -> gonk

yaup -> ecin
yelk -> eyrs
yesk -> eyks

zips -> dunk
zone -> dopy
zoon -> doop

Answer (score 0):

Here's the longest pair for each shift-
0. droogs-willth, helots-svolgh, kilerg-provit
1. banana-zanana
2. anatox-bobine
3. boobook-booboos
4. loppy-spoof
5. paraptera-peneplane
6. bimbos-extern
7. isacco-yogees
8. duende-endued
9. pewterer-temperer, purupuru-torotoro
10. ruffs-speer
11. roctas-twirks
12. furfur-grugru, alruna-lauryl, penile-whydah, and more
13. telembi-tibiale
14. fatwa-inurn
15. hackmack-homecome
16. clover-nebuly, themer-wildly, balcer-openly, a nd more
17. ridgils-zinkify
18. craney-parent, carona-prader, graner-larena, and more
19. alehoof-sholeen
20. bactra-stract, alerta-tipcat, ulaula-zitzit, a nd more
21. judaic-larums
22. coheirs-thorned, conjure-thimber
23. hospices-piehouse
24. fidge-spurt
25. felten-tunful, melvyn-mundal, hutung-refels
The only shifts without a 6-letter pair or longer are 4, 10, 14, and 24,

Comment: While this does indeed answer the question, I am not sure it's wise to embark on an attempt to provide an exhaustive list of every possible word pair as it seems you might be trying to do. (And inviting proper names as candidate "words" makes for a pretty much unending list, as just about anything could be a proper name somewhere.) Perhaps a better way to answer is not with a comprehensive list, but rather a mechanism the OP might use to generate a list themselves (assuming, as I somewhat am, that you're doing this via some programmatic means).

Answer (score 0):

Boon goes to anno with 2, boop with 3, errs with 6,and reef with 19.
Oxen goes to ribs with 6 and dune with 18
Grid goes to etch with 11 and pens with 22
Wiry goes to drib with 0, gule with 3, and mark with 9
Also, snare goes to diver with 22, and drum goes to colt with 6 and frow with 9, so both of the words in "snare drum" have a pair.
I learned the snare-drum thing from the game Ugly Oafs.

Atbash plus Caesar 3 tells you that tips are junk: tips -> junk... and that you'd say "nope" to a pony: pony -> nope

Answer (score 0):

The 4-shift list(needs cleaning), with 2 reverse pairs:
amps -> drol
apod -> dopa(reverse pair)
apps -> dool
aval -> dids
avid -> diva(reverse pair 2)

daal -> adds
dada -> adad
dado -> adap
dapy -> adof
deed -> azza
deid -> azva
dido -> avap
deva -> azid
diva -> avid(return of reverse pair 2)
divs -> Avil(This is the third time I've gotten "Avil!", zero(0), chur(3), divs(4))
dodo -> apap
dods -> apal
dool -> apps
dopa -> apod(return of reverse pair 1)
dowf -> aphy

eddo -> zaap
epee -> zozz

idol -> vaps
idyl -> vafs

joll -> UPSS

lode -> spaz
lowp -> spho

odal -> pads
odds -> paal
odso -> palp
opal -> pods
oppo -> poop
oval -> pids

paal -> odds
paps -> odol
peds -> ozal
poop -> oppo
pozz -> opee

spaz -> lode
spif -> lovy

tizz -> kvee
topo -> KPop

udal -> jads
updo -> joap

zeds -> ezal
zips -> evol

Answer (score 0):

The 5-shift list, cleaned:
Abbe -> Edda
acer -> ecan
aces -> ecam
agar -> eyen
ahem -> exas
aian -> ewer
ajar -> even
anem -> eras
anum -> erks
arba -> ende
aret -> enal
ares -> enam
areg -> enay
argh -> enyx

Baal -> deet
baas -> deem
bael -> deat
band -> derb
bank -> deru
bans -> derm
bara -> dene
barm -> dens
beam -> daes
Bebe -> dada
beet -> daal
bele -> data
bema -> dase
bend -> darb
berm -> dans
bere -> dana
besp -> damp
beta -> dale
bies -> dwam

caba -> cede
carl -> cent
carm -> cens
catt -> cell

faan -> zeer
farm -> zens
fens -> zarm
ferg -> zany
ferm -> zans
flap -> ztep
fleg -> ztay

gaen -> year
gaer(person who goes, old version) -> yean
gaga -> yeye
gaim -> yews
gall -> yett
gang -> yery
garm -> yens
gats -> yelm
gatt -> yell
gaum -> yeks
geen -> yaar
geit -> yawl
gene -> yara
genr -> yarn
gent -> yarl
germ -> yans
geum -> yaks

ixel -> what
ixes -> wham

jaap -> veep
Jane -> vera
jarl -> vent
jerk -> vanu

laim -> tews
lala -> tete
lana -> tere
lane -> tera
lans -> term
lape -> tepa
Lara -> tene
larb -> tend
lasp -> temp
late -> tela(sqap halves again)
leam -> taes
leat -> tael(backwards pair!)
leet -> taal
lell -> tatt
Lena -> tare
lera -> tane
lery -> tang
lesp -> tamp
liar -> twen

maam -> sees
maar -> seen
maas -> seem
Maes -> seam(backwards pair!)
maim -> sews
mair -> sewn
malm -> sets
male -> seta
mama -> sese
mane -> sera
mang -> sery
many -> serg
mare -> sena
marl -> sent
marm -> sens(6eme sens)
mata -> sele
matt -> sell
maul -> sekt
mela -> sate
mend -> sarb
mene -> sara
meng -> sary
ment -> sarl
mere -> Sana
merl -> sant(to sant and to sint)
meru -> sank
mesa -> same(Sqap halves)
mesp -> samp
mewl -> sait
mews -> saim
miks -> swum
mung -> skry

naam -> rees
naan -> reer
nabe -> reda
namu -> resk
napp -> repp
narb -> rend
narm -> rens
naru -> renk
nary -> reng
neba -> rade
neem -> raas
nema -> rase
nerl -> rant
neru -> rank
nesp -> ramp
newt -> rail

paal -> peet
paan -> peer
paap -> peep
paat -> peel
pale -> peta
palm -> pets
pane -> pera
pang -> pery
pans -> perm
papa -> pepe
parm -> pens
paru -> penk
patt -> pell